# How to ignore public_html for image paths

Tags: php, url-rewriting, relative-path

I have setup my own simple framework with a file structure like this:

```
root
    libs
    public_html
        product-images
            image1.jpg
            image2.jpg
            etc...
        controllers
        models
        views
        scripts
```

The problem is, is that my image src for a product has to start with one or two ../'s depending on which page you're on. In some cases I have to declare the full path to the image which looks like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/public_html/product-images/image1.jpg
```

Obviously this isn't very good for SEO.

My question is how can I remove the public_html bit but keep all the images working, without altering the file structure of my site?

Comment: `public_html` should not be on your web-accessible route. It's one directory too low in your server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web server document root should be public_html, not root.

Comment: So I should but things like libs and documentation etc inside public_html?

Comment: @imperium2335 Everything (Your web app files) should be in public_html.

Comment: The typical solution would be to have public assets and an entry point to the the application (eg. index.php) in public_html. Your application entry point can then bootstrap the framework and load necessary files from other directories that aren't publicly accessible .